# Custom UI dropdown button not showing up all commands

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am doing like below to group set of commands into single dropdown but all items are not showing up

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [{ 
    name: 'paragraph', 
    groups:['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], 
    items: ['More']
}];

CKEDITOR.replace(editorName, {
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function () {
            var editor = this,
                items = {}, groupName = 'Justify_Group',
                config = CKEDITOR.config;
            var more_Group = 'More_Group';
            editor.addMenuGroup(more_Group);
            var moreButtons = {
                Subscript: 'Sub Script',
                Superscript: 'Super Script',
                NumberedList: 'Numbered List',
                BulletedList: 'Bullet List',
                Outdent: 'Outdent',
                Indent: 'Indent',
                Blockquote: 'Blockquote',
                RemoveFormat: 'Remove Format'
            }, moreItems = {};
            for (var i in moreButtons) {
                var v = moreButtons[i];
                moreItems[i.toLowerCase()] = {
                    label: v,
                    group: more_Group,
                    command: i.toLowerCase(),
                    order: 1
                };
            }
            editor.ui.add('More', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON, {
                label: 'More',
                name: 'More',
                modes: {
                    wysiwyg: 1
                },
                onMenu: function () {
                    var active = {};
                    for (var p in moreItems)
                    active[p] = null
                    return active;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But same thing works well for Justify buttons. In above list of commands only Bulleted Lists are showing up in dropdown that too with `(properties)` text added to given label.

How can I fix this issue

Comment: Any chance to see a jsfiddle? You can use http://jsfiddle.net/EpokK/B4yGJ/ as a basis

Comment: @Nenotlep Here I placed the code http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/380/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the only thing that you're missing is adding proper menu items.

It's done with [`editor.addMenuItem`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addMenuItem).

### Why adding menu items?

CKEditor UI menus work with menu items, not buttons or anything like that.

Mentioned Bullet List / Numbered List were just a coincidence, most likely because other plugin registered them to use it in context menu (as it reuses menu objects).

### How to fix it in your case?

To make things easier we'll use [`editor.addMenuItems`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addMenuItems).

And it would be it, if you wouldn't include lowercasing for command names. I'll fix it as well.

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [{
    name: 'paragraph',
    groups:['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'],
    items: ['More']
}];

CKEDITOR.replace(editorName, {
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function () {
            var editor = this,
                items = {}, groupName = 'Justify_Group',
                config = CKEDITOR.config;
            var more_Group = 'More_Group';
            editor.addMenuGroup(more_Group);
            var moreButtons = {
                subscript: 'Sub Script',
                superscript: 'Super Script',
                numberedlist: 'Numbered List',
                bulletedlist: 'Bullet List',
                outdent: 'Outdent',
                indent: 'Indent',
                blockquote: 'Blockquote',
                removeFormat: 'Remove Format'
            }, moreItems = {};
            for (var i in moreButtons) {
                var v = moreButtons[i];
                moreItems[i.toLowerCase()] = {
                    label: v,
                    group: more_Group,
                    command: i,
                    order: 1
                };
            }

            editor.addMenuItems( moreItems );

            editor.ui.add('More', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON, {
                label: 'More',
                name: 'More',
                modes: {
                    wysiwyg: 1
                },
                onMenu: function () {
                    var active = {};
                    for (var p in moreItems)
                    active[p] = null
                    return active;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

#### What can go weird?

You'll need to note that the default menu implementation won't show menu items of which related command status is equal to `CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF`.

You can always check this condition by evaluating `editor.commands.bold.state !== CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED`.

You can workaround this problem by passing `onClick` callback that will call your command, rather than providing `command` as a string, but then you'll need also to manually care about command state. Similar trick was used in [language plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/language/plugin.js#L85-L90). Further explainations goes out of scope of this question.

Comment: Interesting.. Could you please add a demo

Comment: Sure, here it is, though still it's exact the same code as in the answer http://jsfiddle.net/o9zd0mqL/

Comment: Thanks it is working and any way to show only labels instead of icon and label?

Comment: From the top or our head, I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do that since it semes to take the icon automatically from other definition. As a workaround you might change menu item keys, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/6yqzkuty/1/ see that they are prefixed in line `moreItems['noicon'+i.toLowerCase()]`.